# How to Calculate with TimeSpan in c#

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I need to divide two TimeSpan.

I have one TimeSpan "worktime" and the other TimeSpan "productive"

What i want is to get as result of worktime/productive is a percentage. I need to get the "added value" (<- I think this is how it's called in english :)),

Comment: `TimeSpan.FromTicks(worktime.Ticks / productive.Ticks)`?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .NET Core you can simply divide the TimeSpans. TimeSpan has a [division operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.op_division?view=net-6.0).

This works:

````
var t1=TimeSpan.FromTicks(1000);
var t2=TimeSpan.FromTicks(100);
Console.WriteLine(t2/t1);
---------------------
 0.1                                                                                                                  ```
````

Answer (score 0):

A Simple example:

```cs
DateTime d1 = DateTime.Parse("10:00:00");
DateTime d2 = DateTime.Parse("13:00:00");
TimeSpan t1 = d2 - d1;                    //   three hours
TimeSpan t2 = new TimeSpan(0,15,0);       //   15 minutes
Console.WriteLine(t1/t2);
```

This outputs: `12`

see: https://onlinegdb.com/ImxwiWk37

Answer (score 0):

```
var addedValue = (decimal)workTime.Ticks/productive.Ticks * 100;
```

The decimal cast is needed or the division will automatically round and you'll get very inaccurate percentages in certain cases.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to get the "added value"

By this, do you mean you want the percentage expressed as a percentage of the overall work time that was productive?

So if the total work time was 10 hours and the productive work time was 9 hours, the percentage of productive work time would be 90%?

If so, the answer is:

```
double percentage = double percentage = 100.0 - 100.0 * (worktime.Ticks - productive.Ticks) / worktime.Ticks;
```